# ActivityNotFoundException with google+

Tags: android, google-plus

I am trying to follow google [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/media) for sharing image, but keep getting this exception:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=jpg flg=0x80000 pkg=com.google.android.apps.plus (has extras) }
            at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1601)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1465)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:820)
```

- My google+ version on the device 5.5.0.93566200
- Device version: lollipop 5.0

Any ideas what it can be?

Comment: `typ=jpg` doesn't seem right (should be `image/jpg`) - where are you loading pictures from?

Comment: @ianhanniballake yeah this is it. I been trying to share bitmap, so I saved it as a file and had to set the mime type by myself. Please add your comment as an answer, so I be able to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `photoPicker.setType("video/*, image/*")` that means that all returned images should have a mime type of `video/*` or `image/*` but it appears you are receiving just `jpg`. The calling photopicker should be changed to return the appropriate mime type - in this case, `image/jpg`.

Note that [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) can be used to easily create shareable links to files to send to other apps (appropriate for `setStream()`) as per the [setting up file sharing training](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html) - it automatically takes care of mime type for you.